# How do i deploy a laravel app on ubuntu server? (ssh)

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, server, ubuntu-server

So i searched the first 2 pages of google for it but i cant seem to get it straight so, the problem is that i have the ip adress and the username and the password for the server and i can connect to it over cmd with ssh username@ipadress but i cant upload my laravel app there.
I installed apache2, nginx, and a lot of other packages for php and composer, but all the tutorials show me how to create a new laravel app there, which is not what i need because i developed the project and i just need to put it up there on the server i will let here a photo of the cmd right after i installed the composer and laravel on it

[the cmd ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXtEd.jpg)

what should i do next ? or how should i upload it...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: You could use an SFTP client to transfer the code. Another common route is to install GIT and simply pull the updates from a repo.

Comment: "*but i cant upload my laravel app there*" - why not? What did you try? Did you get errors?

Comment: so install git on server and just pull the project from there ?

Comment: it says that i dont have such a folder when i try to cd even tho i installed everything @Don'tPanic and i have tried everything to copy everything using a filemanager like filezilla but it failed

Comment: Pulling from a git repository is not necessary but it's a good practice, otherwise it is really hard to maintain and grueling.

Comment: You are not getting great help here bcs you still did not give us a good description of the problem. Edit your question, and explain in detail what you did, and what happend - copy-paste any commands you tried, copy-paste any errors you got.  Vague descriptions like "*it says that i dont have such a folder*" and "*but it failed*" etc are not enough.  Please take a minute to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

are you using git ?
if not first setup git and upload your project to git
then in git you have option deploy project
in that option generate deployment key and use that to clone/deploy your
project into the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can try install WHM and Cpanel [WHM installation here](https://docs.cpanel.net/installation-guide/install/) and if you don't won't to use host managers you can use [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)
and open the ftp protocol on the server or even use github or bitbucket to upload your project and clone it on your server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).